# Access function in react Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a `dump component` looking like so

```
export default class DumpComponent extends Component {
    renderSomething(something) {
        console.log(something)
    }

    render() {     
        return (
            <div>
                { this.renderSomething(something) }
            </div> 
        );
    }
}
```

which I include in a `container`

```
export default class Container extends Component {
    ...

render() {
    <DumpComponent 
     // call function renderSomething() with a variable I pass from here
    />
    }
```

How would I call the function `renderSomething()` from the `Container` with variables, declared in the `container`?

Comment: can you give an example of what `something` might represent?

Comment: so basically you want to call child component method from parent component?

Comment: @DavinTryon that will be some `objects` from the `global state`. Might aswell be in another case a ` boolean` or an `int`, depending where I use the `DumpComponent`. I only wonder how I would call the function `renderSomething()` from `Container`, with a variable defined in `Container`

Comment: @PriyeshKumar I want to call `renderSomething()`, which is defined in `<DumpContainer/>` from `<Container/>`, with variables defined in `<Container/>`

Comment: ok, I'm still a bit unsure on how to guide you because specific context is important with these decisions.  Is the `something` an attribute or property of `DumbComponent` or is it a child?  Sounds like you want the render `this.props.children` and then just set up the child in the way you want.

Comment: @DavinTryon `something` is a variable of the `global object` which I attached to `<Container/>` with `mapStateToProps`

Comment: yeah it means the same ;) It is possible but considered as bad practice. Any solid reason for this architecture,I means at what event you want to trigger `renderSomething()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One the way:

```js
export default class DumpComponent extends Component {
    renderSomething(something) {
        console.log(something)
    }

    render() {     
        return (
            <div>
                { this.renderSomething(this.props.something) }
            </div> 
        );
    }
}

export default class Container extends Component {
    ...

render() {
    <DumpComponent 
      something="The thing"
    />
}
```

Export function togather with component may be useful in your case:

```js
# DumpComponent .js
export default class DumpComponent extends Component {
}
export const doSomething(something) {
    console.log(something)
}

# Container.js
import DumpComponent, {doSomething} from 'DumpComponent'

class Container extends Component {

render() {
    <DumpComponent 
      something={doSomething("The thing")}
    />
}
```

Comment: Also it is possible to pass function of child component to parent and call it from parent but seems it is not good pattern so i will do not add snippet.

Comment: what do you mean with your comment? Would you define the `renderSomething()` function in `<Container/>`? arent you passing a function from child (`DumpComponent`) to parent (`Container`)?

Comment: I guess that like using `ref` to bind child function to parent?

Comment: Yes I mean exactly same pattern like `ref`.

Comment: I've added one more way based on multiple exports.

Answer (score 0):

Use child componentDidMount to get the prop from parent and call function.

```
class Child extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.method(this.props.val);
  }
  method(val) {
    console.log(val)
  }
  render() {
    return <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  }
}

class Parent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child val='hello' />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/v123582/25ebngdd/

Also, it can call function on render()

```
class Child extends React.Component {
  method(val) {
    alert(val);
  }
  render() {
    return <div>{ this.method(this.props.val) }</div>
  }
}

class Parent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child val='hello' />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/v123582/gevzf9kx/